# En Login, cuando hago click y dejo en blanco el email y le doy a iniciar sesion me sale el validateData de la contraseña y no el del email por que?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, email

- En la mainActivity de Login, cuando hago click y dejo en blanco el email o escribo cualquier cosa que no sea un email y le doy a iniciar sesion me sale el validateData de la contraseña y no el del email por que pasa eso si tengo tambien el validateData del email?

https://github.com/Gotzon89/Vinyl-World/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/vinylworld/Login.kt

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: bienvenido, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta por favor, saludos.